# How to comment HTML within React written in TypeScript?

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript

```
class MyClass extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (<div>
            /*<div>{this.state.myVal} Not Working</div>*/
            ///<div>{this.state.myVal} Not Working</div>
            <!--<div>{this.state.myVal} Not Working</div>-->
            </div>);
    }
}
```

I have tried the above 3 ways to comment an entire line. None seem to work. I'm using Visual Studio if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Wrap the `/* the regular JavaScript comment */` in curly braces:

```
{/* <div>{this.state.myVal} Not Working</div> */}
```

A multi-line comment would be:

```
{/* 
  Multi
  line
  comment
*/}
```

Comment: U r a legend. Thx

Comment: So your saying JSX comments work the same in typescript React as they do in JS React.